# When F/A-18 landing on the carrier the main landing gear touching the runaway first or the hook?

Tags: aircraft-carrier, fa-18

The hook in my opinion must be lower enough to make sure that he gets the proper cable, but it is possible that I'm not right.

Comment: Please don't downvote without leaving comments why. The question title seems perfectly clear, even if the question body is garbled. Does the downvoter think this is a poorly posed question? Or is the body text the problem? If it's the text, why not fix it instead of downvote?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in a properly flown approach at the correct attitude the hook touches down first.  Look at photos and video to verify.

Not just the F-18, all carrier aircraft are this way.  (although the carrier airwing has become a lot more homogeneous than it was in years past...)

Comment: In level flight , but not in the landing pattern, just straight away, with the hook down and landing gear the hook is at the same level as the wheels or much lower?

Comment: In level flight, the end of the hook hangs pretty close to straight down, so it simply depends on the length of the hook, the length of the landing gear strut, and the Angle of Attack. The slower the aircraft is, the higher the AOA, and the lower the hook will be.